# Java Threads - Synchronized don

Tags: multithreading, locking, synchronized

```
public class SetGetFail implements Runnable {
// Every thread is assigned a number and has a reference to a SharedObject.
// In main(), a single SharedObject is passed to all threads.
int number;
SharedObject shared;

public SetGetFail(int no, SharedObject so) {
number = no;
shared = so;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
SharedObject shared = new SharedObject(0);
    new Thread(new SetGetFail(1, shared)).start();
    new Thread(new SetGetFail(2, shared)).start();
}

synchronized public void run() {
    setGet();
}

synchronized void setGet() {
// Repeatedly assign this thread's own number to the shared
// object and race to read that number again.
// Exit, if some other thread modified the number in between.
while(true) {
    shared.setNo(number);
    int no = shared.getNo();
    if (no != number) {
    System.out.println("Thread " + number + " sees " + no);
    System.exit(no);
    }
}
}}
```

So my question to the code is, why "synchronized" do not prevent races between these threads? 
Thread 2 should be locked while Thread 1 is getting/setting the Value from shared, but the result is still "Thread 2 sees 1".

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this. I have added an additional log statement just to prove you that it is running. Now let me explain the issue. You have just declared the method that modifies the shared state as this.

```
synchronized void setGet() {
    // ...
}
```

So each thread gets it's own lock and modify the shared data at the same time. That's why your thread-2 sees the value 1 which is set by the other thread. To guard this you need to use a lock which is common to both the thread1 and thread2 instances. For that you need to use an explicit lock object which is shared among both the threads and synchronize using that shared lock. So that's what I have done to solve the issue.

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();

synchronized (lock) {
    // ...
}


public class SetGetFail implements Runnable {
    // Every thread is assigned a number and has a reference to a SharedObject.
    // In main(), a single SharedObject is passed to all threads.
    int number;
    SharedObject shared;

    private static Object lock = new Object();

    public SetGetFail(int no, SharedObject so) {
        number = no;
        shared = so;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SharedObject shared = new SharedObject(0);
        new Thread(new SetGetFail(1, shared), "One").start();

        new Thread(new SetGetFail(2, shared), "Two").start();

    }

    synchronized public void run() {
        setGet();
    }

     void setGet() {
        // Repeatedly assign this thread's own number to the shared
        // object and race to read that number again.
        // Exit, if some other thread modified the number in between.
        while (true) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                shared.setNo(number);
                int no = shared.getNo();
                if (no != number) {
                    System.out.println("Thread " + number + " sees " + no);
                    System.exit(no);
                }
                System.out.println("Thread " + number + " sees " + no);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but my aim is to understand why in the code, there are races? Which Thread is locked(by whom) in this case so the result is like Thread 2 sees 1.

Comment: But with this declaration, the locked object is the "shared object"  or not?

Comment: `static` objects are shared among all the instances. Hence when one thread is in the guarded block the other one has to wait. That keeps race condition from happening.

Comment: It's not the solution of you which is confusing me. Just why in this case(the given code) there a is a race. Because the locked object is the shared instance? Does the synchronnize block one thread or what is happening there ? its not my code..